# Correct implementation of an explicit interface in Fortran

Tags: interface, fortran

I am struggling with explicit interfaces in Fortran.

In one instance, the compiler has requested that I write an explicit interface when I attempt to use an assumed-shape array as a dummy argument for a function or subroutine (i.e., procedure): `Explicit interface required for ... assumed-shape argument`. For example, this would appear like `REAL, INTENT(IN OUT) :: dummy_array(:)` in a subroutine. The `(:)` in the declaration of the array means that the compiler takes care of passing information about the shape of the array to the subroutine. That's handy, but it also means that the compiler **must** know to do this when compiling the call or reference to the procedure. This is not evident from the `CALL` (or reference) alone, so the compiler must have information about the procedure's dummy arguments, hence the need for a explicit interface.

From what I understand, there are three methods for implementing an explicit interface in Fortran:

1. Use a `MODULE` that `CONTAINS` the procedure. This tends to be the recommended approach.
2. Make the procedure *internal* to whatever calls it. This would be like putting a `CONTAINS` statement right before the `END` statement of my main program. The entire code of my procedure would then be placed between these two statements.
3. Write an `INTERFACE` for the procedure. I guess most folks default to this, but it tends to be the *least* recommended approach as it can be a bit laborious.

This brings me to my current problem: In another instance, the compiler gives `Explicit interface required for ... allocatable argument`. Here are the relevant parts following method 1 above:

```
MODULE My_Module
  CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE Clean(my_array_sizes, my_arrays, my_arrays_clean)
      USE Shared, ONLY : dp
      IMPLICIT NONE
      ...
      REAL(dp), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS :: my_arrays_clean(:)
      ...
      ALLOCATE(my_arrays_clean(non_zero)) !new array of correct size
      my_arrays_clean = temp(1:non_zero) !transfer values
    END SUBROUTINE Clean
END MODULE My_Module
```

The problem seems to be with the dummy array `my_arrays_clean`. Here's the call:

```
  CALL Clean(my_array_size, probability, probability_clean) !remove empty values from array
```

The declaration of `probability_clean`:

```
  REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, ASYNCHRONOUS :: probability, probability_clean !store Photon(E_i, depth) values
```

All seems well until I try to compile with `gfortran -g -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -O2 -fall-intrinsics -fopenmp`: `undefined reference to 'clean_'`. I have no idea what's wrong. Of course I can work around this problem to accomplish what I need, but I'd really like to understand the proper way to do this.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `use my_module` where you have the `call clean (...)`.  Please show a complete example for more help.

Comment: I agree with @francescalus here.  gfortran mangles the names of module procedures to something like __MOD_my_module_clean_.  The error message with clean_ does not show the mangled name.

Comment: Something of a tangent: you haven't just written a subroutine to do what `pack` does , have you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about an explicit (or implicit) interface, we aren't talking about a property of the procedure itself.  A procedure has an interface, but this is not entirely the same concept.  Take the module and subroutine as below.

```
module mod
contains
  subroutine sub
  end subroutine
end module
```

The subroutine `sub` has an interface, including such information as it being a subroutine called `sub` with no dummy arguments.  The subroutine of interest from the question has its own corresponding interface.

The "explicit interface" instead is about what information is known about the procedure's interface at the point at which the procedure is referenced.  Look at

```
call sub
end
```

and compare it with

```
use mod, only : sub
call sub
end
```

In the first case, without using the module `mod` the compiler can't even see `sub` as being the subroutine within the module.  `sub` here is an external procedure with *implicit* interface (and not the one in the module).  In the second, `sub` is *use associated*; not only does the compiler now see the module subroutine but it sees the interface (which is now *explicit*).

Likewise, an *internal* procedure (item 2. using the `contains` statement) always has an explicit interface *in its host*:

```
  call sub
contains
  subroutine sub
  end subroutine
end program
```

Third, with an interface block:

```
subroutine sub
end subroutine

  interface
    subroutine sub
    end subroutine
  end interface

  call sub
end program
```

In conclusion: accessible module procedures always have an explicit interface available, but they must first be made accessible with a `use` statement.  Internal procedures are always accessible in the host, always with an explicit interface.  Interface blocks provide an explicit interface, but again the interface block itself must be around where the procedure reference is made.