# Can fortran infer shape of array passed to subroutine?

Tags: fortran, parameter-passing

I read that Fortran (unlike C) knows the size of arrays, and can infer it when I pass the array into function (subroutine). But I cannot make it work.

**Minimum example:**

program.f90

```
program test_arrayPass
    ! === variables
    integer :: n
    real, dimension (:,:),allocatable :: data
    ! === Body
    n = 3
    allocate(data(n,n))
    write (*,*) "DEBUG test_arrayPass : shape(data) ", shape(data)
    call writeToArray( data )
end
```

writeToArray.f90

```
subroutine writeToArray( data )
    real   , dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: data   ! none of these works
    !real   , dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: data   ! none of these works
    !real   , dimension(*,*), intent(in) :: data   ! none of these works
    write (*,*) "DEBUG writeToArray : shape(data) ", shape(data)
end
```

Makefile

```
FC      := /usr/bin/gfortran
FCFLAGS = -g -Og -c -fdefault-real-8 -fbacktrace -fno-align-commons -fbounds-check
FLFLAGS =

SRCS = $(patsubst %.f90, %.o, $(wildcard *.f90))

PROGRAM = program

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(SRCS)
    $(FC) $(FLFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod
```

**Result**

with `dimension(:,:)` it does not know corret size inside  `writeToArray()`

```
 DEBUG test_arrayPass : shape(data)            3           3
 DEBUG writeToArray : shape(data)            1           0
```

with `dimension(*,*)` it produces error

```
    5 |     real   , dimension(*,*), intent(in) :: data
      |                                               1
Error: Non-PARAMETER symbol ‘data’ at (1) cannot be implied-shape
```

Comment: You need the subroutine to have an [explicit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55270873/correct-implementation-of-an-explicit-interface-in-fortran). The easiest way to do this is to put the subroutine in a module and `use` the module.

Comment: You have two (at least) different problems here.  One is a syntax error, but the "wrong result" is that you aren't giving the subroutine an _explicit interface_ in the main program. This is a critical programming error.

Comment: OK, with interface it does work. But it was absolutely not obvious the error has anything to do with interfaces. The code I'm working on has no interfaces anywhere.

Comment: isn't there some easier way which can be inserted everywhere without  either 1) putting everything into modules or 2) writing interfaces everywhere the function is used?

Comment: Whenever you call a subroutine/function you are dealing with interfaces.  By "explicit interface" and "implicit interface" we don't mean interface blocks. "Interface" is what the main program knows about the subroutine.

Comment: You _want_ to put things in modules. Modules are good. They solve many problems you don't know you have yet.

Comment: The main program excepted all Fortran procedures written in the last 30 years should have gone into modules. Not following this simple advice has caused many people much grief they could easily have avoided.

Comment: As @Jalex mentioned put into a MODULE or a MODULE in a library.

Answer (score 4):

Fortran can indeed *assume* (not infer) the shape or size of a dummy argument.

Assuming shape and size are two different things, with different requirements.  With the dummy argument (intent doesn't matter)

```
real   , dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: data
```

you are assuming its *shape* (by using `:` in the declaration). The problem you are seeing with this attempt is that you do not provide an [explicit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42766530/3157076) in your main program. This is such a common mistake that has been covered many times here that I won't expand more: searching for "explicit interface" will provide lots of ideas.

Instead, I'll talk about your other attempt:

```
real   , dimension(*,*), intent(in) :: data
```

This isn't assuming the argument's shape, and neither is it assuming its size.  An assumed size dummy argument would look like

```
real   , dimension(*), intent(in) :: data
```

or

```
real   , dimension(3,*), intent(in) :: data
```

In an assumed size array you can only have "unknown" extent in one of the ranks, and that must be the final one.  However, the syntax for an *implied-shape* array is as you have, but only named constants (and not dummy arguments) may be implied-shape. Your compiler is complaining about this error, not thinking you are trying to talk about an assumed-size dummy array.

Assumed-size array arguments don't require such an explicit interface, but to make this work you'll need to assume just one dimension. (You can make associate a rank-2 array with a rank-1 assumed-size dummy argument if you don't want to guess one of the extents in the subroutine.)

But unless you have a *really* good reason you want to use an assumed-shape `(:,:)` array with an explicit interface. (If you have a good reason to use an implicit interface, you need to think very hard about whether you should be doing what you are doing.)

Finally, with an assumed-*size* array, you can't inquire of the shape of the array (using `shape`), its size (`size`) or its upper bounds (`ubound`). For size and upper bound you can ask about these properties of the initial extents, just not the final. You can use an assumed-size array, but you'll need some other source of information about its shape.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal working example:

```
program test_arrayPass
    ! === variables
    integer :: n
    real, dimension (:,:),allocatable :: data
    ! === Body
    n = 3
    allocate(data(n,n))
    write (*,*) "DEBUG test_arrayPass : shape(data) ", shape(data)
    call writeToArray( data )

contains

subroutine writeToArray( data )
    ! === variables
    real   , dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: data   
    integer :: n, m, k
    ! === Body
    write (*,*) "DEBUG writeToArray : shape(data) ", shape(data)
    n = size(data,1)
    m = size(data,2)

    data = reshape( [(real(k), k=1,n*m)], [n,m] )

end subroutine

end program
```

The problem with your code is that the subroutine `writeToArray` is declared outside the scope of the program. You either contain it within the program, or you put in a module.